# Moving a graphics 2d object with threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, graphics

I am not quite sure why my boat is not moving. 
If anyone could explain in detail that would be great.

This is what creates and shows the boat:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class boatApplet extends JApplet{

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        setBackground(Color.blue);
        // Xposition, YPosition, widthofboat, hieght of boat
        SailBoat boat = new SailBoat(25,500, 350, 400);
        boat.draw(g);
    } //ends method
}
```

This is my sailboat class that draws a boat with poly lines.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
/*
 * sailboat class extends applet intx is starting x position inty is starting y
 * position boatW is the length of the boat boatH is the boat height - the boat
 * and cabin height polyline is used to draw the boat
 */
public class SailBoat extends Applet implements Runnable{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int boatW;
    public int boatH;
    private GeneralPath polyline;

    // constructor takes in x pos, y pos, width of boat, height of boat
    public SailBoat(int xx, int yy, int w, int h) {
        setBackground(Color.blue);
        boatW = w;
        boatH = h;
        x = xx;
        y = yy;
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        /*
         * This method builds the boat from various polyline actionscreaes a
         * graphics 2d object anduses to build the boatrectangle with width of
         * 200 for skybuild the boat basebuild the cabinbuild themastbuild the
         * front sailbuild the backsail
         */
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        // sky
        g2d.setColor(new Color(135, 206, 250));
        // color light blue
        Rectangle2D.Double sky = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 2000, 520);
        // draws a regtangle
        g2d.draw(sky);
        // draws it to g2d
        g2d.fill(sky);
        // fills with color

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        // change color to black
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        // set stroke size 2

        // boat base
        int[] xBoat = { x, x + boatW, x + boatW - 25, x + 25, x };
        // x pos array
        int[] yBoat = { y, y, y + 50, y + 50, y };
        // y pos array
        polyline = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD, xBoat.length);
        polyline.moveTo(xBoat[0], yBoat[0]);
        // moves polyline to first position of array x.y
        for (int index = 1; index < yBoat.length; index++) {
            // for each pos
            polyline.lineTo(xBoat[index], yBoat[index]);
            // draw the lines
        }
        ; // ends loop
        polyline.closePath();
        // closes poly
        g2d.draw(polyline);
        // draws it
        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        // colors the boat base white
        g2d.fill(polyline);
        // fills the poly shape

        // cabin
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        // change color to black
        // cabins x position is x + 60% of the boats length on -1 y to
        // compensate for stroke size
        int[] xCabin = { (int) (x + (boatW * .6)) - 10,
                (int) (x + (boatW * .6)),
                (int) ((x + (boatW * .6)) + (boatW * .15)),
                (int) ((x + (boatW * .6)) + (boatW * .15)) + 10,
                (int) (x + boatW * .6) };
        // cabin y pos
        int[] yCabin = { y - 1, y - 25, y - 25, y - 1, y - 1 };
        polyline = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD, xCabin.length);// gp
        polyline.moveTo(xCabin[0], yCabin[0]);
        // move poly line
        for (int index = 1; index < yCabin.length; index++) {
            // for each pos
            polyline.lineTo(xCabin[index], yCabin[index]);
            // draws lines
        }
        ; // ends loop
        polyline.closePath();
        // close path
        g2d.draw(polyline);
        // draws the poly to g2d
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        // sets color white
        g2d.fill(polyline);
        // fills cabin

        // mast
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        // set color black
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
        // set stroke size for mast to 4
        g2d.drawLine((int) (x + (boatW * .65)), y - 28,
                (int) (x + (boatW * .65)), (int) (y - boatH + 50));
        // draws a line from top of cabin to the remainder of boats height

        // frontsail
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        // set stroke to size 2
        // front sail x position is based on mast pos - 5
        int[] xFSail = { (int) (x + (boatW * .65) - 5), x,
                (int) (x + (boatW * .65) - 5), (int) (x + (boatW * .65) - 5) };
        // front sail y position is set to height to 30 from boat base
        int[] yFSail = { (y - boatH + 50), y - 35, y - 35, (y - boatH + 50) };
        // poly gp
        polyline = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD, xFSail.length);
        polyline.moveTo(xFSail[0], yFSail[0]);
        // moves fs poly line
        for (int index = 1; index < yFSail.length; index++) {
            // for each pos
            polyline.lineTo(xFSail[index], yFSail[index]);
            // draw line to
        }
        ; // ends loop
        polyline.closePath();
        // closes path
        g2d.draw(polyline);
        // draws path to g2d
        g2d.setPaint(new GradientPaint(x, y, Color.white, 450, y, Color.black));
        // set paint as gradient
        // fills sail
        g2d.fill(polyline);

        // backsail
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        int[] xBSail = { (int) (x + (boatW * .65) + 5),
                (int) (x + (boatW * .65) + 5), x + boatW,
                (int) (x + (boatW * .65) + 5) };
        int[] yBSail = { (y - boatH + 50), y - 35, y - 35, (y - boatH + 50) };
        polyline = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD, xBSail.length);
        polyline.moveTo(xBSail[0], yBSail[0]);
        for (int index = 1; index < yBSail.length; index++) {
            polyline.lineTo(xBSail[index], yBSail[index]);
        }
        ; // ends loop
        polyline.closePath();
        g2d.draw(polyline);
        g2d.setPaint(new GradientPaint(x, y, Color.white, 300, 200, Color.black));
        g2d.fill(polyline);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int time = 0; time < 1000; time += 10){
            x += 1;
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ` am not quite sure why my boat is not moving` Which boat? The boat in the `boatApplet` is never moved.

Comment: Make the variables x, y, boatW and boatH volatile. e.g. `volatile public int x;`

Comment: The boat in boatApplet is the one I need to move. It is named boat.

Comment: As I said - your variables should be volatile. Also you need to add boat to boatPanel.

Comment: I changed them to volatile and added it to a panel inside a frame and it seems to not be moving still. If I remove the try catch it moves instantly, but the thread sleep seems to be messing it up somehow.

Comment: Call `super.paint` before you do any custom painting (in fact, use a `JPanel` instead and override it's `paintComponent` method (and call `super.paintComponent`) and get double buffering for free). Use a Swing `Timer` instead of `Thread` and consider using `JApplet`, better yet, don't use applets at all and considering using a `JFrame` as your top level container instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, based on the snippets of code of two things jump out of me...

1. Why does `SailBoat` extend `Applet`, when you are calling it's `draw` method from `boatApplet`
2. Calling `repaint` within `SailBoat` will do nothing, as it's not actually a displayable component (it's not "added" to anything and based on how you are trying to use, it should be)

   - Remove `extends Applet` from `SailBoat`, it's only confusing the matter
   - Move the `Thread` to the `boatApplet`, have it call a `move` method on the `SailBoat` which will update the internal position of the object, then have `boatApplet` call `repaint` on itself
   - Call `super.paint` before doing any custom painting
   - Use a Swing `Timer` instead of a `Thread`, it updates within the context of the EDT making it safer to update the state of the UI. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details
   - Avoid applets if you can, they have a bunch of there own issues which you probably don't need to deal with right now
   - Move your core logic to a `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method (and call `super.paintComponent`) and get double buffering for free, then you can add this panel to what ever top level container you want